# Linux IRQ handling in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to understand how IRQ handling works in Linux on an ARM platform, and I'm not able to understand the assembler macro "handle_irq" (in [arch/arm/kernel/entry-asmv.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S#n35)). This is the macro, when CONFIG_MULTI_IRQ_HANDLER is defined:

```
ldr r1, =handle_arch_irq
mov r0, sp
adr lr, BSYM(9997f)
ldr pc, [r1]
```

I suppose it is loading the address of the function into r1, the stack pointer to r0, the link register to 0x9997F, and the pc to the function address.

But I don't understand the `=` in front of `=handle_arch_irq`, I don't understand why the return address is always fixed (it would change, if a line is added in the code), and why it is using ldr on the pc, and not directly moving.

Comment: Fairly basic assembly syntax: [the `LDR=` pseudo-instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289875065.html); [numeric local labels](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731175956.html) (note the GNU assembler doesn't impose armasm's 0-99 limit) - there's no 0x prefix there, and `ADR` specifically takes a label argument, not an immediate, anyway. Presumably `handle_arch_irq` is a function pointer, thus needs dereferencing to call - how's it defined?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a bit difficult to search these little things when you don't know exactly where to search. It seems I was only half correct. `handle_arch_irq` is a function pointer: in ASM, handle_arch_irq is a global identifier with reserved space 4, and in C, it is assigned to a function call (`handle_arch_irq = mdesc->handle_irq`).

Comment: Basically, *How do I do a function pointer in ARM assembler*.  This is how you do it.  There is no `bl [r1]`; it could also be `ldr r1, [r1]` and `bl r1`.  At some point there may have been extra code between `ldr pc,[r1]` and the *9997* label.